# Problem in getting values in Numpy Polynomial

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, polynomials

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev as T
X=np.array([1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
data=np.array([2.312,4.563,6.765,7.897,12.456,7.568,6.543,3.453,6.654,9.678,11.453,19.567])
p=T.fit(X,data,6)
plt.plot(X,data)
plt.plot(*p.linspace(60))
```

**I generated a data for which i am doing fitting using numpy polynomial chebyshev. the chebyshev is fitting the data but i dont know how am i going to get the the fitted data values from this code?
Is there any way to get the fitted values or do i have to change the whole code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your code, the `Chebyshev` data structure `p` holds what is needed to get any fitted value. For example, the expression

```
list(zip(*p.linspace(60)))
```

gives a list of 60 points, where each `x` coordinate is a value betwee `1` and `13`, which were the bounds you gave for `x` values. The corresponding `y` value is the fitted value for the `x` value. You can then just choose which of the points you want.

Here is the result for that expression after running your code:

```
[(1.0, 2.541204853676799),
 (1.2033898305084745, 2.808340815346975),
 (1.4067796610169492, 3.0743429556868413),
 (1.6101694915254239, 3.348688496878723),
 (1.8135593220338984, 3.637978305373278),
 (2.016949152542373, 3.9462679999194794),
 (2.2203389830508478, 4.27538454719654),
 (2.4237288135593222, 4.625228345047772),
 (2.6271186440677967, 4.994060793316362),
 (2.830508474576271, 5.3787773522831195),
 (3.0338983050847457, 5.775166088706113),
 (3.2372881355932206, 6.178151709462269),
 (3.440677966101695, 6.582025082790894),
 (3.6440677966101696, 6.980658247139146),
 (3.8474576271186445, 7.367704907609403),
 (4.050847457627119, 7.736786420008617),
 (4.254237288135593, 8.081663262499552),
 (4.4576271186440675, 8.396391994853994),
 (4.661016949152542, 8.675467705307872),
 (4.864406779661017, 8.913951945018319),
 (5.067796610169491, 9.107586150122668),
 (5.271186440677966, 9.252890551399389),
 (5.474576271186441, 9.347248571530947),
 (5.677966101694915, 9.388976709968594),
 (5.88135593220339, 9.37737991539911),
 (6.084745762711865, 9.312792445813466),
 (6.288135593220339, 9.196604216177416),
 (6.491525423728814, 9.031272633704036),
 (6.694915254237289, 8.820319920728197),
 (6.898305084745763, 8.568315925182945),
 (7.101694915254238, 8.280846418677859),
 (7.305084745762712, 7.964466882179304),
 (7.508474576271187, 7.626641779292636),
 (7.711864406779662, 7.275669317146346),
 (7.915254237288136, 6.920591694878116),
 (8.11864406779661, 6.5710908397228325),
 (8.322033898305085, 6.237369630702523),
 (8.52542372881356, 5.930018609918223),
 (8.728813559322035, 5.6598681814437874),
 (8.932203389830509, 5.437826297821619),
 (9.135593220338983, 5.274701634160355),
 (9.338983050847459, 5.1810122498344615),
 (9.542372881355933, 5.166779737785785),
 (9.745762711864407, 5.241308861427015),
 (9.949152542372882, 5.412952679147101),
 (10.152542372881356, 5.68886315641859),
 (10.35593220338983, 6.074727265506907),
 (10.559322033898306, 6.574488572781565),
 (10.76271186440678, 7.190054313629292),
 (10.966101694915254, 7.920987954969137),
 (11.16949152542373, 8.764187245369472),
 (11.372881355932204, 9.713547752766893),
 (11.576271186440678, 10.75961188978718),
 (11.779661016949154, 11.889203426668058),
 (11.983050847457628, 13.08504749178393),
 (12.186440677966102, 14.325376059772596),
 (12.389830508474578, 15.583518927263885),
 (12.593220338983052, 16.827480176210102),
 (12.796610169491526, 18.019500124818624),
 (13.0, 19.115602766086262)]
```

Comment: thanks sir.. it works.. 
but i want all the x values and all the y values in seperate array means how am i going to put all x values in one array and all y values in another one?

Comment: For that, use `xvals, yvals = p.linspace(60)`.